# Get only number and dot in a column with mac value Replace/SubStr - ORACLE

Tags: sql, regex, replace, oracle10g, substring

if I have in the table_1, in column called mac value as [10.10.10.10] or [10.200.1]
how can I select just only the number: 10.10.10.10 or 10.200.1 ?

it's something with substr but I don't know how to use it :(

```
 select ???? from tabel_1...??
```

please help me

Comment: What's wrong with oracle documentation? http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php you will need to use it combined to the `length` function

Comment: but the length is not always the same

Comment: My dear sir, I'll let you know that I capitulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this if the [10.100.1.1] isn't necessarily at the start of the string:

```
select regexp_replace('foo [10.100.1.1]whatever', '^.*?\[([0-9.]+)\].*$', '\1') from dual;
```

if it is:

```
 select regexp_replace('[10.100.1.1] whatever', '^\[([0-9.]+)\].*$', '\1') from dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use REGEXP_REPLACE

remove '[' and ']' with all alphanum after:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('[10.100.1.1]ASDA1D', '(\[)|(\]([[:alnum:]]*))', '') from dual
```

Comment: yes its ok, but I just want to select the number...
I have something like 

      "[10.01.01] ABCDEF"

and I want just number

     10.01.01

Comment: `select REGEXP_REPLACE('[10.1.1.1] ASDAD', '(\[)|(\])|([[:alpha:]])', '') from dual;` works

Comment: when you have 
`select REGEXP_REPLACE('[10.1.1.1] ASD99AD', '(\[)|(\])|([[:alpha:]])', '') from dual;`
it didn't work because you got `10.1.1.1 99`

Comment: no no, i edited the answer show,
`select REGEXP_REPLACE('[10.100.1.1]ASDA1D', '(\[)|(\]([[:alnum:]]*))', '') from dual`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Oracle's [regular expression functions](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) for pattern matching.  This pattern will capture anything between `[` and `]` regardless of length.

```
select regexp_substr('[105.102.10.10]', '^\[(.*)\]$', 1, 1, null, 1) value
from dual;
```

If you don't care whether or not the pattern starts with `[` and ends with `]` then remove the `^` and `$` characters.

```
select regexp_substr('[105.102.10.10]', '\[(.*)\]', 1, 1, null, 1) value
from dual;
```

Comment: but it caputre also with `[` and `]`

Comment: @user2207426 - Sorry, I fixed it.  use the new one.

Comment: @user2207426 - Not sure.  I copy/pasted the above and it works fine for me.

Comment: 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go with regex you can also use `instr()` buildin function an `substr()` like this:

```
SELECT substr('[10.10.10.10] asdf', 2, instr('[10.10.10.10] asdf', ']') - 2)
FROM dual
```

Searches for the position of the closing `]` and reduces this position by 2 for both `[` and `]`